# How can I make my program automatically scroll in order to see binded class in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="index">
        <div v-if="channel.ChName">
          <img
            :src="'http://uyanik.tv/conf/images/'+channel.Image"
            height="100px"
            :class="{selectedIndex:currentIndex === index}"
            :ref="index"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have binded an img components class to a dynamically changing index and in screens with lower resolutions, I want my program to display that item by scrolling through automatically. I don't want it to overflow. Is it possible any kind of solutions? I am also adding some images so you can comprehend the issue I am currently facing.

**Overflowed version:**

[image: Overflowed version]

**Current version:***

[image: Current version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

component template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div v-for="(channel,index) in this.channels" :key="index">
        <div v-if="channel.ChName">
          <img
            :src="'http://uyanik.tv/conf/images/'+channel.Image"
            height="500px"
            :class="{selectedIndex:currentIndex === index}"
            ref="channelImage"
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

(notice the :ref="index" changed to ref="channelImage")
in your component code, you should add a watcher to the currentIndex property (assuming is reactive and inside your data() function.

```
watch: {
    currentIndex() {
      window.scrollTo(0, this.$refs.channelImage[this.currentIndex].offsetTop);
    }
  },
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why did you replace index to channelImage inside ref directive?

Comment: whenever you assign a ref on your dom it won't be dynamic as you previously wanted to be with index. So basically, your ref was taking the name index, as an array of dom elements (because it's inside the v-for loop). So, then you would access the ref as this.$refs.index[0] i.e. I've found it simpler to put a meaningful name to the reference. Actually it should be channelImages.